# How to set header-text in amplify-confirm-sign-up Vue component without removing default behaviour?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-vue

I am configuring a custom message in the amplify-authenticator sign-up confirmation by using the supplied slot and passing a "header-text" to my `<amplify-confirm-sign-up>` as per the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue#confirm-sign-up):

```js
<amplify-authenticator username-alias="email">
  <amplify-confirm-sign-up slot="confirm-sign-up" username-alias="email" header-text="Custom Confirm Text"/>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

This works fine for the custom header-text, but it changes the default behaviour of the `<amplify-confirm-sign-up>` component. Specifically, when the user confirms the sign-up (in my case, supplies the one-time-confirmation code emailed):

- it then no longer auto-populates the email address for the confirm-sign up
- once user enters the code (thus confirming the sign-up) it doesn't log them in automatically.

I want to retain the above default workflow - what can I do to customise the header title and keep it?

Comment: Following their Angular documentation, I'm having the exact same problem.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( this flow in my app is still less then ideal due to this amplify-authenticator issue.